# Qt aligning the application to the top left corner on screen

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Recently I am working on a Qt Gui application with c++ and I need to align my window to top left corner when I run the application. (**It should open on the top left corner by default**).

Is there any way I can do this on the code or by Qt designer?

I would be really glad if someone could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposing you have a main window, move it to the top left corner of the primary screen rectangle  (get the screen object, and its geometry, from the `QApplication` instance):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScreen>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;

    QRect screenrect = a.primaryScreen()->geometry();
    w.move(screenrect.left(), screenrect.top());
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Do you know any other way that does this, but not by changing the main.cpp?

Comment: You can put the (more or less) same code in the main window constructor, I think. What's the trouble with changing the main?

Comment: Just for more plain code. It has no trouble I was curious, thank you.

Comment: Remind not to forget "#include <QScreen>"